# Getting the size of a file that exceeds System.Int64 range (theoretically possible)

Tags: c#, .net, stream, ntfs, system.io.fileinfo

To find out the length of a file (in bytes) you would normally use `FileInfo.Length` or `System.IO.Stream.Length` (is there a difference?). Both are of type long, i.e. System.Int64, hence the [maximal possible value](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int64.maxvalue.aspx) is:

```
9 223 372 036 854 775 807
```

Now it seems some filesystems, such as NTFS5 or Microsoft's Resilient File System (ReFS) theoretically allow a maximum file size that exceeds the Int64 range - according to [this source](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/b8/archive/2012/01/16/building-the-next-generation-file-system-for-windows-refs.aspx), ReFS limits maximal file size to 2^64-1 bytes, which equals to (for readability purposes):

```
18 446 744 073 709 551 615
```

How would one go about determining file size in such case - however hypothetical it may be - and would it impact normal Stream operations (such as using Read/Write methods etc.)?

Comment: no one has a file that big....

Comment: Use an unsigned 64-bit integer?

Comment: I've seen some pretty large numbers here at Google for "total storage sizes" etc... but I don't think it would become a realistic concern even here.

Comment: With the current hardware, it is impossible to create a file that big, but when that time comes, Microsoft will add an extra property to the .NET framework (if it still exists at that point) for your grandchildren that returns a `BitInteger`.

Comment: @MitchWheat, suppose that I for whatever reason append together multiple disk images. The question is meant to be purely hypothetical.

John Willemse that was my first thought, thanks; but what is the reason that .NET operates with long instead of ulong in the first place?

Comment: if it's not a problem for google, then you are wasting your time asking.

Comment: @MitchWheat but I cannot know a priori if it's a problem for google or not, so condescending comments like this absolutely do not help. I think it's a fair question to ask.

Comment: @MitchWheat, I would not agree. The question is related to the .NET circle, and google is not addressing these technologies. For the sake of curiosity, I am sure there will be people (including myself) who want to know the alternatives in such even hypothetical scenario.

Comment: Let me know when you have a file even 1/1000 that size....

Comment: They operate with long, because there's no need for anything else _right now_ or the foreseeable future.

Comment: @MitchWheat, it is not about of ever reaching it, it is the desire of knowing how to handle such case. I am sure this can be answered regardless of the possibility for practical occurence

Comment: @MitchWheat That's why it's called a hypothetical/theoretical question. Last I checked, it was ok to ask questions that may not have direct practical value here. No need to be antagonizing.

Comment: Let's say you used terrabyte standard size hard drives, and your file spanned multiple drives... You'd need >8000 cubic meters of harddrive, and that's even without cabling and supporting interfaces!

Comment: @MitchWheat a better question would be _why_ they wouldn't make better programmers.. and even then, some synthetic neurobiologists may have a thing or two to say, even if not pragmatic at the time.

Comment: @MitchWheat, I am sure we are all going to be a better programmers if we ask hypothetical questions and struggle for the answer (I don't mean post them all here). I am sure you did that many times yourself walking the path to become a developer. Back then, there might not have been a stackoverflow site to ask on, this does not mean you should not ask. If you do not want to know about > int64 file-sizes, do not stop others from wanting. The ones who ask hypothetical questions are those most likely to give an answer one day.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How would one go about determining file size in such case

There's nothing built-in to the .NET framework. When your file gets bigger, both `FileInfo.Length` and `System.IO.Stream.Length` will throw an exception. You will have to fall back to calling the Windows API directly (if the Windows API supports this currently).